# Why can’t we convert potential energy into linear kinetic energy but , can convert it into rotational kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rotation, rotational-kinematics

Here is a question from my book -

> A meter stick is held vertically with one end on a rough horizontal surface. It is gently allowed to fall on the ground. Assuming that the end at the floor does not slip, find the angular speed of the rod when it hits the floor.

To get the answer we simply convert the gravitational potential energy of the rod into rotational kinetic energy, i.e

> $\frac{mgl}{2}=\frac{I\omega^2}{2}$

Here $l$ is $1$ of course.

Now the rod does zero work to the top most point because the tension in the rod is perpendicular to its motion.

Why cant we conserve its energy and say that $(dm)gh=\frac{(dm)v^2}{2}$ where $dm$ is the mass of the point on the top of the rod and then by using the equation $v=l\omega$ we can find $\omega$ . But this gives me the wrong answer and the first approach gives the right answer. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to integrate that expression

Comment: What is the value of h in the second approach?

Comment: @SchrodingersCat the length of the rod

Answer (score 2):

One problem with the second approach is that you used h = the length of the rod. That would be right if the entire rod dropped by h. Only the top does.

Likewise, the rod is rotating. The top moves fastest. The bottom doesn't move at all.

Your approach would work if you divided up the rod into small pieces and figured out $mgh$ and $mv^2/2$ for each piece.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is right, but you get to the wrong conclusion because you messed up your calculation. For each "piece" $dm = \frac{M}{L}\,dy$ you have:
Kinetic energy: $\frac{1}{2}v^2\,dm = \frac{M}{2L} y^2\omega^2\,dy$
Potential energy: $gy\,dm = \frac{gyM}{L}\,dy$

Integrating both of those from $y = 0$ to $y = L$ and equating them you get

$\int_0^L \frac{M}{2L} y^2\omega^2\,dy = \int_0^L\frac{gyM}{L}\,dy$
$\frac{M}{2L} \frac{L^3}{3} \omega^2 = \frac{gM}{L} \frac{L^2}{2}$
$\implies \omega^2 = \frac{MgL}{\frac{1}{3}ML^2} = \frac{MgL}{I} $

that is the right result.   $I = \frac{1}{3}ML^2$ is the moment of inertia of a rod rotating on one end.